# Textbox cannot empty or enter digit 0 c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, validation

i use this code :

```
 private void textBox5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text) || textBox5.Text.Length == 0) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Textbox Cannot Empty or digit 0");
                textBox5.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

when I empty the textbox appears messagebox I expected . but when I enter the number/digit "0" appears messagebox success ? for validation i used numeric. for validation I only want to use the numbers 1-9. anybody can help me?

Comment: Side-note: `|| textBox5.Text.Length == 0` is redundant since `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` includes it already

Comment: You don't want to check the *length* of the textbox when comparing to `0`, you want to check the actual *text* - `textBox5.Text == "0"` (or parse to an int and check for `0` rather than `"0"`)

Comment: Where are you applying validation?

Comment: @petelids how this condition will ever work `textBox5.Text.Length == "0"`. Length is an int

Comment: @PawanNogariya he doesn't use the length property to check but the actual text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` checks only for `null`, not for the char `'0'`. If you want to check the digit too, you need to check in addition for `textBox5.Text.Equals("0")`:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text) || textBox5.Text.Equals("0")) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Textbox Cannot Empty or digit 0");
    textBox5.Focus();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}
e.Handled = true;
```

**Edit:** Here's a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RvnAm5)

---

**Q:**

> what if the digits entered are 00000 ??

**A:**

1. You can use `int.TryParse` as in the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678079/textbox-cannot-empty-or-enter-digit-0-c-sharp/37678172#37678232) of [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter)
2. Or you can use the following Regex for vaidation: `\^0*$\`

Again the [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FM9VMO)

Here you need: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text) || Regex.Match(textBox5.Text, "^0*$").Success) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Textbox Cannot Empty or digit 0");
    textBox5.Focus();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}
e.Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to validate numbers and allow only integers between 1 and 9, you should use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (e.KeyChar == 13)
{
    int number;
    if(int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out number) && number >= 1 && number <= 9)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Textbox must contain an integer between 1 and 9");
        textBox5.Focus();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Side-note: `|| textBox5.Text.Length == 0` is redundant since `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text)` checks that already.

Comment: thanks for the help, I have tried . but I have been getting the solution of @Maximilian .

Comment: @Underdog: you're welcome. Although i don't understand how the accepted answer helps to achieve your desired result: _"for validation I only want to use the numbers 1-9"_

Answer (score 2):

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text) || textBox5.Text.Length == 0) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Textbox Cannot Empty or digit 0");
                textBox5.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            }
```

In this piece of code you're checking if the text length is 0

```
// "" will have length 0 
// "0" will have length 1
```

If you want to check if you have the digit 0 in that box you need to check the following:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text) || 
    textBox5.Text == "0")

textBox5.Text.Length == 0 // you don't need this anymore if youre using IsNullOrWhiteSpace as IsNullOrWhiteSpace checks for null, string.Empty, white spaces
```

Of course the most beautiful way to check that is to try to parse textBox5.Text and to see if you get a digit between 1 and 9 using the following code:

```
int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out number) && number > 0 && number < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] removeCaracter = { "0",... };
            foreach (var item in removeCaracter)
            {
                textBox5.Text = textBox5.Text.Replace(item, "");
                textBox5.SelectionStart = textBox5.Text.Length ;
                textBox5.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
        }
```